# My string is empty after DropDownLists's Selected Index Changed function

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have page with 5 Drop down lists and one Grid View ( Data source is Data Table ). I am trying to filter my grid view with values of drop down lists and doing that successful only with one filter. So problem is in filtering from more drop down lists in same time. 
My function for filtering

```
private void Filter()
{

    String filter = "Marka IS NOT NULL";
    if (Fmarka != "") { filter += Fmarka; }
    if (Fram != "") { filter += Fram; }
    if (Fprocesor != "")  { filter += Fprocesor; }
    if (Fkamera != "") { filter += Fkamera; }
    if (Fekran != "") { filter += Fekran; }

    table.DefaultView.RowFilter = filter;
    GridView2.DataBind();

}
```

Every IF statement is for one drop down list. Every drop down list has Auto post back enabled.
This is my code example for third drop down list..

```
protected void DropDownList3_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e){
    Fprocesor = " AND Procesor='" + DropDownList3.SelectedValue.ToString() + "' ";

    Filter();
}
```

I am getting good results only for one drop down list every time ( I checked my string values in background with breakpoints, every time when Filter functions fire, all my strings are "" like on start of the program then getting values... )

Comment: Are you sure the events are bound to their methods?

Comment: @preciousbetine Yes